# Yii2. How to build subexpression

Tags: yii2

How can i build query with subexpression, without using `yii\db\Expression` and raw sql. For example this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE archived = 3 AND ((group = 2 AND status = 3) OR (group = 3 AND status = 2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build such condition using array expressions:

```
$users = (new Query())
    ->from('user')
    ->where(['archived' => 3])
    ->andWhere([
        'or',
        [
            'group' => 2,
            'status' => 3,
        ],
        [
            'group' => 3,
            'status' => 2,
        ],
    ])
    ->all();
```